# Python - How to make operations over a sliding window on 2D arrays?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, sliding-window

I would like to make non simple operations on a 2D arrays using a sliding window in Python. 
I will be more precise with an example. Suppose we have a 10x10 matrix and a sliding window of 3x3, starting from the very first element (1,1) i would like to create a new matrix of the same dimension where at each element i will have the result of the operation (percentile of the numbers, complex operations and so on) considering all the elements covered by the window. I can do this with the function **np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided**, but for big arrays it gives memory error.
Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to create a new matrix with the same values as the windows in order to alter its items without modifying the main matrix? If so, I think that you can use the copy method in order to avoid modifying the main matrix.

[Numpy Copy method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.copy.html)

Comment: No i mean that the new matrix will be the result of the operations on the first matrix using the sliding window